# How do i parse an email into meaningful content(especially text/html part)? - python/pop3

Tags: python, email, html-email, pop3

OK. Here's my code:

```
hotmail = poplib.POP3_SSL("pop3.live.com", 995)

hotmail.user("username")

hotmail.pass_("password")

mail_1= hotmail.retr(1)

message_1 = email.message_from_string("\n".join(mail_1[1]))

for part in message.walk():
    print part.get_content_type()

    print "\n"

    print part.get_payload()

    print "----------------------------------------------"


mail_2 = hotmail.retr(2)

message_2 = email.message_from_string("\n".join(mail_2[1]))

for part in message.walk():
    print part.get_content_type()

    print "\n"

    print part.get_payload()

    print "----------------------------------------------"
```

The problem i'm having right now is, for `mail_1` which is a hotmail welcome mail, everything works all right especially `text/html` part, it's correctly formatted. But for `mail_2` which is a `multipart/alternative` message, what i got from `text/html` is a mess, there's lots of fillers like `=0D` and `3D` and `=` all over the place, some typical lines look like this:

```
<td id=3D"middle_column=
_content_cell" style=3D"background-color:#ffffff;=0D
                                                    -webkit-border-radius:6=
px; -moz-border-radius:6px; border-radius:6px;=0D
                                                    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1p=
x 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);=0D
                                                    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3=
px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);=0D
                                                    box-shadow:0 1px 3px rg=
ba(0,0,0, 0.2);">=0D
=0D
                                                        <span style=3D"font=
-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;=0D
                                                        font-size:16px; lin=
e-height:22px; color:#424242;">=0D
```

So what do I do to get a meaningful `text/html` message body?

Comment: Is there a text-only part? Most HTML emails also have a separate plaintext part that you should be able to read directly. Have you looked at `get_payload` in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [quopri](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) module:

```
import quopri

decoded_text = quopri.decodestring(encoded_text)
```